# shinyCAPTCHA does not trigger the validation properly

Tags: shiny, recaptcha

I would like to integrate captcha verification into my shiny app (like [this](https://github.com/carlganz/shinyCAPTCHA)). But it has an unexpected behavior.

If this line:

```
recaptchaUI("test", sitekey = "6LeIxAcTAAAAAJcZVRqyHh71UMIEGNQ_MXjiZKhI")
```

is inside the UI, my app works fine (I mean, the validation is triggered when the **checkbox and the button are clicked**)

However, if it is inside `renderUI`, the validation is triggered only by clicking the checkbox (there is **no need to click the button**)

Here is my minimal working example:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyCAPTCHA)

ui <- fluidPage(
  # With this line, the captcha works perfectly
  recaptchaUI("test", sitekey = "6LeIxAcTAAAAAJcZVRqyHh71UMIEGNQ_MXjiZKhI"),
  uiOutput("body")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  result <- callModule(recaptcha, "test", secret = "6LeIxAcTAAAAAGG-vFI1TnRWxMZNFuojJ4WifJWe")
  
  output$body <- renderUI({
    fluidPage(
    # Inside renderUI, it does not work properly.
    #recaptchaUI("test", sitekey = "6LeIxAcTAAAAAJcZVRqyHh71UMIEGNQ_MXjiZKhI"),
    uiOutput("humansOnly")
    )
    
  })  
  
  output$humansOnly <- renderUI({
    req(result()$success)
    tags$h1("For human eyes only!")
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I have an app with several modules, that's why I need to use `renderUI`. What is the error in my code?

I appreciate any help!